# What's the Minimum Stream Volume on AndroidDevices and how to get it Pre SDK28

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

They've added in 28(P) the function

```
AudioManager.getStreamMinVolume(int streamType)
```

I've checked two phones. One returned 0 (max 15) the other one returned 1 (max 8). I assume that AndroidPhones somehow use "Steps". Setting the StreamVolume to 0 didn't work on the phone where the minVolume returned 1. Even setting the StreamVolume with

```
adjustStreamVolume(streamType, ADJUST_MUTE, 0)
```

failed.

Are there Phones that use percentage from 0 to 100 because

```
public static final int ADJUST_MUTE = -100;
```

? And my question: How to get the minStreamVolume for a specific streamType pre Pie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the formal way to find the minimum volume of a stream type.

```
/**
     * Returns the minimum volume index for a particular stream.
     *
     * @param streamType The stream type whose minimum volume index is returned.
     * @return The minimum valid volume index for the stream.
     * @see #getStreamVolume(int)
     * @hide
     */
    public int getStreamMinVolume(int streamType) {
        IAudioService service = getService();
        try {
            return service.getStreamMinVolume(streamType);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Dead object in getStreamMinVolume", e);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current volume index for a particular stream.
     *
     * @param streamType The stream type whose volume index is returned.
```

Comment: That's the code from AudioManager that was added in SDK 28. I asked for pre 28.

Comment: I did some checking around. I found one older post on here that dated back to 2011 asking about min. And the accepted answer was you try for 0 and if 0 is not accepted use 1. I tried to find something more formal saying it and was unable to do so. I was also unable to re find the post or I would have linked it. It also didn't give code as to how to do it but I was assume it is a try catch because it said try then if it fails.

Comment: I'll accept your answer cause of your last comment. It would be nice if you could edit your post. It looks like there isn't really a way to get the information.